# Change default duration for Calendar events on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, calendar

In the Calendar app on macOS Mojave, is it possible to change the default duration for an event from one hour to twenty minutes?

Comment: For future searchers, I've linked the duplicates in this order because the other historically has more hits & the Terminal answer was provided first.

Answer (score 2):

Open Terminal and enter the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.iCal 'Default duration in minutes for new event' 30
```

(example is 30 minutes)

You will need to quit and restart Calendar app for the change to take effect.

+++

To reverse the change and revert back to defaults, use Terminal command:

```
defaults delete com.apple.iCal 'Default duration in minutes for new event'
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible. The closest you can get is to open the Day or the Week view, and add a new event by dragging from the begin time to the end time. However, you'll be limited to a duration which is a multiple of 15 minutes:

[image]

(of course, you can freely edit the begin and end time afterwards, but that would work for the one-hour events too)